# DialogFlow Intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a new Agent and number of intents in that.Each intent will accept the any data which user gives.I used @sys.any:any in Training Phase.

Now i want to filter the garbage values which user gives like "sdfasfasdf".
when user gives meaningless as a request then give response from fallback intent.

How to clear this type of situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should not use the `@sys.any` everywhere and create entities based on other `@sys` filters to capture the exact information.

Comment: Thanks for answer Abhinav i am new to dialogflow. Will you please elaborate.

Comment: please share more details, code snippets, screenshots of intents and webhook if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogflow is intended to capture the basic understanding of what a user says as part of a conversation. Making everything a `@sys.any` entry and trying to handle it yourself in code defeats that purpose.

Use intents to create phrases that you expect the user to say. If you're expecting particular kinds of values in response to your questions, turn those into entities and create phrases around those entities.

Then handle nonsensical or useless input in your Fallback Intent.